# Web3j no transaction pooling with REST

Tags: web3j

I have setup an application with jhisper gateway with one microservice in REST linked to Web3j. Idea is when you store an object in the database, you notarize it in a private ethereum blockchain.

So, I have a REST Post service to create the object in database, then he call a smartcontract to notarize it in the blockchain.
Everything is working for One object at a time but if I make a loop without wait method, it will create in the blockchain only the first one. Like it didn't call it several time...

when I look to the log of the miner (txpool.status)

```
txpool.status
{
  pending: 1,
  queued: 0
}
```

I have never more than 1 in pending, such as he did 'nt see the 100 other...

```
        List<Long> thingIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++) {
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
        HttpBasicAuth authentication = (HttpBasicAuth)apiClient.getAuthentications().get("basic");
        authentication.setBasePath("http://localhost:8080/");
        authentication.setCredentials("admin","admin");
        Date d = new Date();
        String a= ""+d.getTime();

        ThingResourceApi agentResourceApi = new ThingResourceApi(apiClient);
        thing = new Thing();
        thing.setName("Paris"+(new Date().getTime()));
        thing.setCollectorAddress("0x3baeb8019a9cc9c488aa9355dc522e023a3b406d");

        thing = agentResourceApi.createThingUsingPOST(thing);
        thingIds.add(thing.getId());
    }
```

if i add the following snipped at the end of the loop, it works

```
try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am sorry if it is a little confusing, hope you will have an interest to give me idea to solve it...

Francois